# "Cannot connect to server" Bot Xcode

Tags: macos, ipad, xcode, osx-server

I have a Bot running for my app, with just a regular development account. I want to be able to download the Product that is created, but when I go to the Bot web page, I get an error "Cannot connect to ". I find this a little strange, because I can hit the server web page. Any ideas? Do you have to have an enterprise account to donwload the product?

The iPad has all the correct profiles etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, sort of. It has to do with the SSL certificate on the server. I ended up purchasing an SSL from GoDaddy because I could never get a self signed to work. I would recommend using some of the other methods, like storing your plist in DropBox if you don't want to pay for an SSL and can't get the self signed to work.

This was after reaching out to apple and reading a post in the developer forums. Apple hopefully will fix this in the future.